# ExtJS 3.4 Radiogroup strech turn off

Tags: extjs

I have the problem with set the width each radio button in the radio group.

```
xtype: 'container',
id: 'cntCompany',
layout: 'hbox',
fieldLabel: 'Company',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        id: 'rdogrpCompany',
        items: [
            { id: 'rdoIT', boxLabel: 'IT', name: 'rdoCompany', inputValue: 'IT', width: 40, checked: true },
            { id: 'rdoCOMMS', boxLabel: 'COMMS', name: 'rdoCompany', width: 40, inputValue: 'Comms' },
            { id: 'rdoGROUP', boxLabel: 'GROUP', name: 'rdoCompany', width: 40, inputValue: 'Group' },
            { id: 'rdoALL', boxLabel: 'ALL', name: 'rdoCompany', width: 40, inputValue: 'All', margins: '0 0 0 30' }
        ]
    }
]
```

I set the width each radio button but it is not working properly.
Why this radiogroup strech as same width column and ignore width: 40?
How I set the width for each radio button?

Comment: I think this is caused by the Layout you choose. It seems to overrides the child items width. But this is just a guess...

Comment: @sra I think it's not a layout problem because radio button width works fine without radio group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Combo-Group / Radio-Group is using the column Layout to align the grouped elements. and that uses 'auto' as default value if nothing else is set.

> The controls will be rendered one per column on one row and the width
>   of each column will be evenly distributed based on the width of the
>   overall field container. This is the default.

Based on the API it is a Layout problem. Note that ExtJS uses default Layouts if you don't define one. So change either the layout or try if `columns: 1` solve your issue.

[API-Link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup-cfg-columns)

*EDIT:*
Based on the comment the correct answer is `columns: [40, 40, 40, 40]`

Comment: Thank you @sra . I tried 'columns: 1' in the Ext Designer but I can't input 1. It seems like a bug. Of course, it works after manually edit. For other people, I want to give each width for each radio button. Column:1 is not the answer I want because it make vertical radio button array. The answer will be 'columns: [40, 40, 40, 40]'. Thank you again